# How can i make sure a html switch has completely changed state?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a switch in html as follows in reactjs

```
<Switch onChange={this.handleChange} checked={this.state.checked} />
```

the handlechage is as follows:

```
   handleChange(checked) {
    this.setState({ checked });
   sessionStorage.setItem("value", checked);
   }
```

But when i use check the checked state in the session it hasnt changed to the new value. So how can i put a spinner or something else to make sure that the state has changed and i get the new value ?

Answer (score 2):

As `setState` is asynchronous (in considerations that `setState` changes the state that triggers re-rendering), the `checked` value in this case will not be immediately updated.

And as mentioned in the [React Documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#setstate), one of the possible way is to use a `callback` function:

```
handleChange(checked) {
    this.setState({ checked }, () => {
        // do things that depends on the update here
        sessionStorage.setItem("value", checked);
    });
}
```

More info could be check on the difference between `sync` and `async` components.

Comment: This doesnt work , because i get the value and pass it to my mvc controller after switching and the value hasnt changed

Comment: I need to click the button twice for it to read the new value from client side

Comment: @Belinda My suggestion would be to provide more code related to the `MVC` controller, as it is hard to tell what is the problem rn.

Comment: On the other hand, perhaps you can check more about `componentDidUpdate()`, assuming you are using class components instead of function components.

Comment: @Belinda And the problem is likely (I guess) due to the controller did not wait for the `setState` to be finished as well.

Comment: can i make the controller wait for setstate to be finished. Maybe something in javascript that is spinning until finished ?

Comment: @Belinda The brief answer is, yes. But the method to do so largely depends on how you structure your controller and stuff, which might require the use of keywords like `await` and `async`, or components like `<Route>` and `<Suspense>`.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness, but if u could provide more sample code, maybe I could provide a more accurate answer for you.